# phpmysqlnd_ms plugin does not load

Tags: php, php-5.5, mysqlnd

The [mysqlnd_ms](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd-ms.php) plugin is not being detected by my PHP5.5 setup.

I've installed [mysqlnd](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php) and enabled it with PDO and mysqli.

```
> php -m | grep mysqlnd
mysqlnd
```

It shows up in `php -i`

```
> php -i > dump; vim dump
mysqlnd

mysqlnd => enabled
Version => mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: bf9ad53b11c9a57efdb1057292d73b928b8c5c77 $
Compression => supported
core SSL => supported
extended SSL => supported
Command buffer size => 4096
Read buffer size => 32768
Read timeout => 31536000
Collecting statistics => Yes
Collecting memory statistics => No
Tracing => n/a
Loaded plugins => mysqlnd,debug_trace,auth_plugin_mysql_native_password,auth_plugin_mysql_clear_password,auth_plugin_sha256_password
API Extensions => mysql,mysqli,pdo_mysql
```

This is the ini file for mysqlnd, where i enable `mysqlnd_ms`

```
cat /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini 
; configuration for php MySQL module
; priority=10
extension=mysqlnd.so
mysqlnd_ms.enable=1
mysqlnd_ms.config_file=/etc/php5/mysqlnd_ms_plugin.ini
mysqlnd_ms.force_config_usage=1
```

And this is the json file with the cluster configured

```
cat /etc/php5/mysqlnd_ms_plugin.ini
{
    "mysqlndapp": {
        "master": {
            "master_0": {
                "host": "192.168.0.45",
                "socket": "3306"
            }
        },
        "slave": {
            "slave_0": {
                "host": "192.168.0.45",
                "port": "3307"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I installed mysqlnd using apt

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

At runtime, I get this error

```
php -d mysqlnd_ms.enable=1 -d mysqlnd_ms.config_file=/etc/php5/mysqlnd_ms_plugin.ini test.php 
PHP Warning:  mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /var/www/symfony-cli/Symfony/app/test.php on line 3
PHP Warning:  mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /var/www/symfony-cli/Symfony/app/test.php on line 3
[2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```